# Negative observations for scipy.stats.gamma.fit()

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In statistics, Gamma distribution only takes positive observations. When I use scipy.stats.gamma.fit() to fit gamma distribution by Maximum Likelihood Estimate and put observations with both negative and positive values in, I can get a reasonable result. However, mathematically this is not correct. The documentation says that ***With method="MLE" (default), the fit is computed by minimizing the negative log-likelihood function. A large, finite penalty (rather than infinite negative log-likelihood) is applied for observations beyond the support of the distribution*** ([rv_continuous.fit()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit)). Can anyone explain what was happening in this scenario? Thanks.

Comment: SciPy's `gamma` has three parameters, one of which is the *location*, `loc`.  If `loc` < 0, there can be negative variates.

Comment: Yes. But it does not make sense that gamma distribution takes negative observations for the support of gamma distribution is (0, infinite).

Comment: The support of the three parameter gamma distribution is (loc, infinity).  If loc < 0, then the support includes negative values.

Comment: Yes. The function takes negative values when loc < 0. However, in mathematics, gamma distribution can not take negative values.

Comment: You are still only considering the two-parameter distribution, which has a shape parameter and a scale parameter.  You are correct that the two-parameter gamma distribution can not take negative values.  The third parameter, loc, is simply a translation, and it allows negative values (when loc < 0).  The usual two-parameter distribution corresponds to loc = 0.  (See, for example, https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366b.htm, where the location parameter is called μ.)

Comment: Note that you can tell the `fit` method to fix to location to be 0 with the argument `floc=0` (e.g. `shape, loc, scale = gamma.fit(mydata, floc=0)`.  If you do that, then you will get the error that you expected if your data contains negative values.

Comment: Thanks. So the gamma distribution in scipy.stats is a general form.